# return objects with no associated data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Game < Event  
  has_many :statistics, :dependent => :destroy

  ...
end

class Statistic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
end
```

I want to make a named scope that only returns games that have no statistics.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`named_scope :no_statistics, :include => :statistics, :conditions => ['statistics.id IS NULL']`